# writing values generated from different functions in a single file

Tags: python

I have written this code and what I am trying to do here is to write the values generated from this function and another one which are in stored as lists in `timeList` and
`parameterList`. I am not exactly supposed to write the values of `timeList` in the same function I guess. It should probably be done in a separate function. I have already got the `timeList` in `curve.dat` file. Now I have to write the `parameterList` in the same file but not following the values of `timeList` but on the right side of the `timeList`. The `timeList` in `curve.dat` file is:

> 0.07
>   0.06
>   0.08
>   0.12
>   0.11
>   0.09
>   0.14
>   0.05
>   0.06

The parameterList is:

`[0.744527502029805, 1.3466145472841764, 2.8186875392157371, 3.2822440320192392, 7.9272007790523782, 6.0493081375991276, 9.2609232787439613, -611.06135600582172, -399.75236270058838]`

Now I should have the contents of curve.dat file as the following:

```
0.07       0.744527502029805  
0.06       1.3466145472841764  
0.08       2.8186875392157371  
0.12       3.2822440320192392  
0.11       7.9272007790523782  
0.09       6.0493081375991276  
0.14       9.2609232787439613  
0.05       -611.06135600582172  
0.06       -399.75236270058838
```

Could someone help with this please. Thank you.

```
def time(transcriptionFile) :
    with open("transcriptions.txt", "r") as tFile :
        timeList = []
        parameterList = []

        for line in tFile :
            li = line.split()
            if li :
                start_time = (int(li[0]) / 10000000.)
                end_time = (int(li[1]) / 10000000.) 
                duration = ((int(li[1]) -int(li[0]))/10000000.)
                timeList.append(duration) # t(u) values for plotting the bezier curves

                with open("curve.dat", "w") as outFile:
                    outFile.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in timeList))

                poly = poly_coeff(start_time, end_time, duration)

                Newton(poly, 0.42, parameterList)
```

Comment: @ F.J: Thank you for editing my post. I couldn't do it myself though I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not write `timeList` to the file while inside the `for line in tFile` loop.
Notice how many times you are opening and closing the file (very inefficient). Also notice if you open the file in `'w'` (write) mode instead of `'a'` (append) mode, it overwrites the previous contents...

Instead, wait (delay gratification!) until you have both `timeList` and `parameterList` assembled. Then do

```
with open("curve.dat", "w") as outFile:
    for t,p in zip(timeList,parameterList):
        outFile.write('{t}\t{p}\n'.format(t=t,p=p))
```